# Выборка графиков и вывод на экран

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Есть таблица с полями:
Дата начала приема врача
Дата окончания приема врача
(В этих полях храниться время на каждый день):
Понедельник
Вторник
Среда
Четверг
Пятница
Суббота

На экран надо выводить графики работы врачей на текущую неделю. Как это сделать?
Все даты недели я получил, есть идея проверять промежуток дат на вхождения в текущую неделю.

Comment: во-первых, вывести куда ( в консоль, в html или куда-нибудь ещё)? во-вторых, а какие собственно возникли проблемы? если вы осилили БД, то почему также не можете осилить и вывод?

Comment: В html. Проблема что график может  быть сразу на месяц, неделю им даже 1 день. Решил спросить чтобы написать правильно.

Comment: ну вот и в какие возникли проблемы? как должен этот график выглядеть (ожидаемый результат) и что получилось у вас (текущий результат).

Comment: Проблема такая: Как выбрать график на текущую неделю, например если график сделан на 2 недели или на месяц. И еще как выбрать время из 2-х графиков, даты которых пересекаются в одной неделе. Например с 30.11.2020 по 05.12.2020

Comment: вы описали слишком мало данных: приём у кого, как храните графики, зачем нужны даты приёма, его начала и конца и т.д. выбрать — это что? выделить с помощью выделения мышкой, или выделить в отдельный список? всю информацию в вопрос (кнопка "править" слева от вашего интерактивного профиля).